# How do I determine a nice spread of colours for 345 Rows?

Tags: excel, vba, colors

This might be an question for a graphic designer.

I have an MS Excel sheet, and I want to color 345 cells with different shades. It helps with usability. Now there are millions of shades/tints/colors, so I'm not short of options. But I would like them to be as distinct as possible.

https://www.mgc.ltd.uk/post/the-56-standard-colours-in-excel-the-colorindex-values-or-pallet

This post gave me a good start, but it only produces 56 shades. Now those are "standard colors" according to the article, but .... what if I changed the tint, or the RGB values?

I don't have any real understanding of the different dimensions of color.

What I'm hoping to achieve, is to take a number, like "345" and have a VBA script give me 345 different shades/colors/tints that are as distinctly different as possible.

```
Range("A1").Select

For i = 1 To 56
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = i
Next
```

I could iterate through a billion options of

```
 With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = ______
    .TintAndShade = _____
    .PatternTintAndShade = ______
End With
```

but I don't understand how they relate to each other.

Advice please?

Comment: 345 is a *lot* of colors, if you're expecting users to be able to tell them apart.

Comment: Some online tools available - eg: https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/

Comment: Use the `RGB()` function to pick your colours. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function

Comment: sidenote - presume one reason mgc's produces 56 shades due to _ColorIndex_ property which only has 56 colours, you could generate 345 diff RGB combo by RBG function which can produce millions options. But like others said it's hard to distinguish in Excel though.

Comment: 345 is approximately 343 is 7*7*7. Divide 255 to 7, you get about 36. Iterate all color components (R, G, B) over 7 values (1 * 36, 2*36 etc) - you get 343 different colors, spanned evenly over RGB color space. Note that for human eye they are not distributed evenly - but this is quite different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can bring up this screen using Excel > Home > Fill Color > More Colors > Custom

[image: Excel Custom Colors using RGB]

**Rainbow using Excel VBA - Thank you NHS!**

I wrote this VBA program during lockdown 2020, 5th November to 2nd December. Use the Sub sb100x100 to make the rainbow visible. On a Mac use the Sub sbMac100x100. This changes the size of the cells so that you can watch the rainbow being drawn. It is slow but then that's what I needed during lockdown, it passes the time!

The standard equation of a circle is (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2, where (h,k) is the center. For example h = 25 k = 25 r = 20 from quadratic x^2 + y^2 = r^2

[image: Rainbow using Excel VBA]

```
Sub doit()
 sbAllWhiteAYL606
 Call fnRainbow117(600, 660, 500)
 Range("A1").Select
End Sub
Function fnRainbow117(h, k, r)
' RGB rainbow
' red 255, 0, 0
' orange 255, 127, 0
' yellow 255, 255, 0
' green 0, 255, 0
' blue 0, 0, 255
' indigo 75, 0, 130
' violet 148, 0, 211
'
' red
 red = 255
 green = 0
 blue = 0
' red 255, 0, 0
' orange 255, 127, 0
' yellow 255, 255, 0
 For c = 1 To 21
 For x = 1 To r 'Step 10
  y = (VBA.Sqr((r * r) + 1 - (x * x)))
  xh = x + h
  yk = y + k
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk - (2 * y)).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
 Next x
 r = r - 1
 green = green + 12
 Next c
'
' yellow
 red = 255
 green = 255
 blue = 0
' yellow 255, 255, 0
' green 0, 255, 0
 For c = 1 To 10
 For x = 1 To r 'Step 10
  y = (VBA.Sqr((r * r) + 1 - (x * x)))
  xh = x + h
  yk = y + k
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk - (2 * y)).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
 Next x
 r = r - 1
 red = red - 25
 Next c
'
' green
 red = 0
 green = 255
 blue = 0
' green 0, 255, 0
' blue 0, 0, 255
 For c = 1 To 10
 For x = 1 To r 'Step 10
  y = (VBA.Sqr((r * r) + 1 - (x * x)))
  xh = x + h
  yk = y + k
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk - (2 * y)).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
 Next x
 r = r - 1
 green = green - 25
 blue = blue + 25
 Next c
'
' blue
 red = 0
 green = 0
 blue = 255
' blue 0, 0, 255
' indigo 75, 0, 130
 For c = 1 To 10
 For x = 1 To r 'Step 10
  y = (VBA.Sqr((r * r) + 1 - (x * x)))
  xh = x + h
  yk = y + k
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk - (2 * y)).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
 Next x
 r = r - 1
 red = red + 7
 blue = blue - 12
 Next c
'
' indigo
 red = 75
 green = 0
 blue = 130
' indigo 75, 0, 130
' violet 148, 0, 211
 For c = 1 To 10
 For x = 1 To r 'Step 10
  y = (VBA.Sqr((r * r) + 1 - (x * x)))
  xh = x + h
  yk = y + k
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
  Cells(xh - (2 * x), yk - (2 * y)).Select
  Call fn1rgb(red, green, blue)
 Next x
 r = r - 1
 red = red + 7
 blue = blue + 8
 Next c
fnRainbow117_Exit:
 Range("A1").Select
End Function
Function fn1rgb(r, g, b)
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    DoEvents
End Function
Sub sbAllWhiteAYL606()
 Range("A1:AYL606").Select
     With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    DoEvents
 Range("A1").Select
End Sub
Sub sbNoHeadings()
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub
Sub sb100x100()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 0.75
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 0.083
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
Sub sbmac100x100()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 1#
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 0.1
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting! What is the function "fn1rgb(red, green, blue)"?

Comment: @Maxcot sorry should change `sb1rgb` to a function called `fn1rgb` and it will work.

Comment: @maxcot I have updated the code and added a routine to use on the Mac. Have fun!